# Power button to kill locked sessions

Tags: debian, shutdown, kde-4

I have a headless Debian server that will auto-login a user to KDE on startup and then locks the screen/session.

If I press the power button while the KDE session is locked, the button is ignored.
If I press the power button while the KDE session is not locked, the server is shutdowned as expected.

Is there a possibility when pressing the power button to end the locked sessions and proceed with the power down as normal?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the autologin?

Comment: I needed to start a vnc server and could only do that after the user has logged in.

Comment: Is there a reason that can't be done using init scripts, or using a non-graphical login?

Comment: I tried init script but the vnc server was not starting. In the end i managed to make it work this way and i don't intend to change it unless i really have to.

Comment: OK, fair enough.